# How do you extend the Code Review Window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I would like to write an extension to Visual Studio that allows me to add additional UI elements to the existing code review window. This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260261/extending-visual-studio-code-review-functionality) appears to define exactly what I would like to do. But the answer does not explain how this would be achieved while suggesting that it can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable section in page, please refer to the following code.

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer teamExplorer;
  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorerPage page;
 teamExplorer = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer))
               as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer;
 page = teamExplorer.CurrentPage;
 var sections = page.PageContent;
 Type type = typeof(System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink);
 FieldInfo f1 = page.PageContent.GetType().GetField("linkCancelDecline", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
 PropertyInfo pinfo = sections.GetType().GetProperty("IsEnabled");
 pinfo.SetValue(sections, false, null);
sections.GetType().GetProperty("IsEnabled").GetValue(sections, null);
```

If you want to add sections to pages, please refer to the following link, which provide related code.

https://binary-stuff.com/post/getting-start-with-a-team-explorer-plugin-for-vs-2013-part-4
https://github.com/jakobehn/GitFlow.VS/tree/master/TeamExplorer.Common

Comment: Thanks the first link answers the question.